# For Loops not activating

Tags: java, for-loop, indexing

So I'm trying to get a program that reads a file, with the length of the file as the first line.  And then finds the index of the minimum and the maximum in the file.  The annoying thing is, that for some reason, my findMin and findMax methods are not working.  It seems as if they are bypassing the for loops.  I'm sure I'm just making a silly mistake, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver00 {
    public static int minpos;
    public static int maxpos;
    public static double min;
    public static double max;
    public static int numitems;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        int numitems = infile.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[numitems];
        for (int k = 0; k < numitems; k++) {
            array[k] = infile.nextDouble();
        }
        infile.close();
        int minPos, maxPos;
        minPos = findMin(array);
        maxPos = findMax(array);
        System.out.println("Minimum value: " + minPos);
        System.out.println("Maximum value: " + maxPos);
    }

    private static int findMin(double[] apple) {
        for (int x = 0; x < numitems; x++)
            // not activating
            if (x == 1) {
                if (apple[x] < apple[x - 1]) {
                    min = apple[x];
                    minpos = x;
                } else {
                    min = apple[x - 1];
                    minpos = x - 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (apple[x] < min) {
                    min = apple[x];
                    minpos = x;
                }
            }
        return minpos;
    }

    private static int findMax(double[] banana) {
        for (int x = 0; x < numitems; x++)
            // not activating
            if (x == 1) {
                if (banana[x] > banana[x - 1]) {
                    max = banana[x];
                    maxpos = x;
                } else {
                    max = banana[x - 1];
                    maxpos = x - 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (banana[x] > max) {
                    max = banana[x];
                    maxpos = x;
                }
            }
        return maxpos;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know why down-vote here?

Comment: Sometimes silly mistakes are not well tolerated.  But you're right that this is a dumb newbie mistake that doesn't indicate, say, failure to read the error message or failure to do a minimal Google search for an answer.  (You can upvote if you feel the downvote was unfair.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public static int numitems;` is `ZERO` that is why your for loop is not executed

**Why numitems  ZERO?**

Because the integer your are getting at `int numitems = infile.nextInt();` statement will be assigned to method local `numitems` variable not for the instance variable.

Comment: to clarify - you are declaring it twice - once as a static class member and once as a local variable inside main

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout: I was typing that info as you commented.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 int numitems = infile.nextInt();
```

declares a new *local* variable that hides the static field and gets changed instead. Therefore the field numitems is never assigned anything and stays at 0.
Change this to

```
 numitems = infile.nextInt();
```

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout: That I don't know, but that is the topic of a whole other question.

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout -- He probably declares so much stuff static so that he doesn't have to create and manage an object instance.  Not terribly unreasonable for a "toy" program.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare int numitems = infile.nextInt(); you're writing over your global static variable.

Additionally, this code is likely not to work for another reason.
1:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numitems; x++)  //not activating
      if (x==1){
            if (apple[x] < apple[x-1]){
                min = apple[x];
                minpos = x;
                }
            else{
                min = apple[x-1];
                minpos = x-1;
                }
            }
         else{
            if (apple[x] < min){
                min = apple[x];
                minpos = x;
                }
            }
```

This is a mess, and will likely break because for loops start at 0, not at 1, and min isn't yet instantiated; far easier is:

```
if(numitems<=0)
    return 0; //In case there isn't actually a value in your list.
minpos=0;
min=apple[0]
for(int x=1;x<numitems;x++)
{
    if (apple[x] < min)
    {
        min = apple[x];
        minpos = x;
    }

}
```

with a corresponding change to maxpos.